# JS - ReferenceError not defined when referencing a property dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to reference a property of a variable that is being set dynamically. When the first console.log line runs with vars[sv.name] it outputs the correct result. When I reference vars[] further down in the eval statement I get a ReferenceError.

```
vars = {};
        // Get the array of current variables 
        if (cache[msg.guild.id]) {
            cache[msg.guild.id].variables.forEach(sv => {
                if (sv.type == 'Text' || sv.type == 'Number') {
                    vars[sv.name] = sv.value;
                    console.log(vars[sv.name] + ' ' + sv.name);
                }
            });
            console.log(vars);
            Object.keys(action).forEach(e => {
                try {
                    var newVal = eval('`' + action[e] + '`');
                    action[e] = newVal;
                }
                catch(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                 //console.log(`key=${e}  value=${action[e]}`)
            });
        }
```

Error I'm getting is: "ReferenceError: c is not defined" where "c" is the property name.

Here's what the object looks like that I'm referencing:
`{ c: 'ok' }`

And here's what's in the cache variable:

```
{ 
    variables: [ { name: 'c', value: 'ok', type: 'Text' } ] 
}
```

And `action[e]` in this case is: `${vars[c]}`

Comment: I'm not clear on what the intention is here. Why do you need to `eval` the content of the action? All you need to do is get the value of one key, why not just store `"c"` in `actions[e]` and then do `vars[action[e]]`? Or use tagged templates or something. The current system looks odd to say the least.

Comment: c is just the property name, it corresponds to a string that's coming from user input. Since it's coming from user input and there could be any number of these variables in the string I can't use a template

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox where 'eval' code gets run.  For security reasons there is a separate scope.

Comment: Is there a way to circumvent this? I need to substitute the value into the string dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Actually it looks like 'eval' has access to the global scope.  Try using a global variable.

Comment: my understanding was that doing vars = {} instead of var vars = {} made it global?